# Java: Syntax problem

Tags: java

I want to use the above code for one more argument, say`args[2]`. Where should I make changes? Will `nextline` remain the same or does it become `nextline[1]`?

Comment: Why did you declare *nextLine* as an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `args[2]` holds the name of your second data input file, then you'll have to create a second reader for that file. A quick solution with a simple for loop, skipping exception handling:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++){
  CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(args[i]));
  String [] nextLine;
  while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
         // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
         //System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + "etc...");

         for (String value:nextLine)
           System.out.print(value+" ");
         System.out.println();
  }
  reader.close();
}
```

The number of values in a line can be determined with `nextLine.length`.

Comment: +1, but you may want to move move the nextLine declaration out of the for loop and wrap the loop code in a try/finally to ensure the file is closed.

Comment: no, actually I want to put the entries of files into the tables on mysql database. they have different number of rows and columns. so i need to keep them different. Like args[1] has 9 rows and args has 6 rows. Then How would I set the limit of nextline here in the last line of code. nextline[0], nextline[1]....????

Comment: nextline.length??? where it is in your code?Do I need to use any library for csv code?

Comment: @shilps - (1) `nextLine.length` is not in my code example. use System.out.println to print it to the console, just to learn what it's for. (2) Syntax errors, they're independet from the OS environment, you need to tell us *where* you have errors. (3) - Please, please, start with a tutorial on Java, you're starting to ask pretty basic question.